# Removing noise from lines with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Please take a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/xSDG43/1/.
I'd like to remove this kind of "noise" between paragraphs. I cannot really avoid them due to irregularities in the documents I'm processing.

The pattern above yields the result I seek, but if implemented in my code it does not.

```
import re

txt = re.sub(r'/^.{1,16}\n/gm', r'', txt)    # no
txt = re.sub(r'^.{1,16}\n', r'', txt, re.M)  # no
txt = re.sub(r'^.{1,16}\n', r'', txt)        # no
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is in `txt`, and what should the "noiseless" version be?

Comment: Try `txt = re.sub(r'^.{1,16}\n', r'', txt, 0, re.M)` If you use the re.M, the fourth parameter is the count, in this case I have added 0.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Excellent! Thank you. ScottHunter cf. the link. 
[Correct reference?]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects